# Excitation of electrons

Tags: electrons

IF an electron is excited, what can it do? Dissipate the energy to the object, emit another photon?

IF a photon hits an object and NO electron is excited, what happened there?

What are the possible causes of electron excitation?

Comment: Also, can a non-exact photon (to get the electron to the required energy level) cause electron excitation?

Comment: The question of photons with non-exact energies is addressed here: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49583/exactly-equal-and-at-least-in-electron-excitation